ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader' angular with capacitor (Android Studio)
I have a problem on the FileReader. Currently, I have an angular app and applied a capacitor (Ionic) to It. On my angular app, I integrated an NSWAG to it. Its perfectly working on chrome.
When running the app on android studio, there is an error on the post API.

Msg: ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader':
parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
This is the code from web.api.client.ts

function blobToText(blob: any): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>((observer: any) => {
        if (!blob) {
            observer.next("");
            observer.complete();
        } else {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = event => {
                observer.next((event.target as any).result);
                observer.complete();
            };
            reader.readAsText(blob);
        }
    }); }

For the capacitor.config.ts, not sure If I need to add some codes to it.
import type { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.myapp.app',
  appName: 'MyApp App',
  webDir: 'dist',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  server: {
    cleartext: true,
  },
  plugins: {
    CapacitorHttp: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  }
};

export default config;

I made some research but the solutions doesn't work. The above codes are working on my Angular project.

Have you debugged to check what type blob is when running the app from Android Studio? (Is it a Blob, File or something else?)

Hi Jarich, I found you are using CapacitorHttp, so could you help us check the settings when you use CapacitorHttp.
